# Manipulation of textInput in R Shiny server

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I'm a beginner in R shiny.I need to use the text input in different function calls,it shows error the most of the time.Firstly I have printed the input value,it works fine.But if I try to use it a function it says some error.How to use them as normal variable as we use in other languages?

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
output$sstock_name <- renderText(input$stock_name)    
av_api_key("YOUR_API_KEY")
sri1 <- data.frame(av_get(symbol = sstock_name, av_fun =     
"TIME_SERIES_DAILY",interval = "15min", outputsize = "compact"))    
})
```

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
titlePanel("Stock prediction"),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  textInput(inputId = "stock_name",label = "Enter the stock 
  name",value = "MSFT")
),
mainPanel(
  h2("Stock data"),
  textOutput("sstock_name")
)
)
))
```

Error:
Warning: Error in av_get: object 'stock_name' not found
Stack trace (innermost first):
    44: av_get
    43: data.frame
    42: server [/home/jeyakumar/Documents/Projects/Stock Prediction/Star/server.R#28]
     1: shiny::runApp
Error in av_get(symbol = stock_name, av_fun = "TIME_SERIES_DAILY", interval = "15min",  : 
  object 'stock_name' not found

Comment: Please update your post to include the error.

Comment: Error added with traceback